# Accessing clicked model in an Ember.ArrayController

Tags: ember.js, controller

I have a small Ember.js app that shows the current month as a list filled with `day` models. Think a calendar where you can click certain days to highlight them.

```
App.HolidaysNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: { 
    toggleSelected: function() {
      console.log(this.day);   # --------> day is undefined here
    }
});

App.HolidaysNewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  days: function() {
    return [
      this.store.createRecord('day'),
      ...
    ];
  }.property()
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="holidays/new">
   <ul>
     {{#each day in days}}
       <li {{action "toggleSelected"}}>{{day}}</li>
     {{/each}}
   </ul>
</script>
```

How can I know which `day` model was clicked in the action handler? I know there is a `currentModel` but this is an `ArrayController` with multiple models.

When I create an Ember component in the template and pass it the `day` model from the loop it works but this means I am handling the behavior in the component and I think I am supposed to leave that up the the controller.

Thanks!

Comment: How about pass the day in the each to the action? Like {{action "toggleSelected" day}}

Comment: @blessenm Thanks, that works. If you convert your comment to an answer I can accept yours as you were first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your toggleSelected function to allow another argument

```
App.HolidaysNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: { 
    toggleSelected: function(obj) {
      console.log(obj);  
    }
});
```

and then in the action send the object

```
 {{#each day in days}}
   <li {{action "toggleSelected" day}}>{{day}}</li>
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea you could pass params to an action like that.